# DataGridView: Add new row using an array or List<t>

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I've two listbox-elements in my form.
The items in listbox1 are representing the columns in my DataGridView,
the items in my listbox2 are representing the rows in my DataGridView.

```
foreach (var el in listBox1Elements)
{
// code...
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Since items in listbox1 can be added or deleted I've a problem with my current solution.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test","some","data","even","more","data");
```

I wonder if there is a solution for using a List.
Then my code could look something like this:

```
foreach (var el in listBox2Elements)
{
   myList.add("some text");
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(myList);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
        foreach (var el in listBox2Elements)
            myList.add("some text");

        foreach (var item in myList)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.., item.., item..);
```

or

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myList.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach (var el in listBox2Elements)
{
   myList.add("some text");
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(myList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

well thats some hard task to do without a store object. 
there you could easily go:

```
//Not taking guarantee for this approach
Store.DataSource.add(new object[]{"some text"});
Store.DataBind();
```

or you define a new Data source object and fill it with the list items (via loop) and do that again after doing:

```
(list<string>) data_list.add("some text");
//repopulate data object and set a Store.DataSource;
Store.dataBind();
```

and for deleting objects you would delete them from the `list<string>` item and update the store like above

```
//population for the data object:
for(int x=0; x<= data_list.length(); x++)
{
 data.add(new object[]{data_list[x]});
}
```